# Make a class have function with 3 parameter (int,string,double ) with return value int in Kotlin

Tags: function, class, kotlin, parameters, return-value

```
fun main() {
    val thr = THR()
    thr.kotlin()
    thr.hitungthr(5000000, "1", 1.5)
}

class THR {
    fun kotlin() {
        println("Perhitungan THR")
    }

    fun hitungthr (gajipokok: Int, masakerja: String, jumlahthr: Double): Int {
        var MasaKerja = masakerja.toInt()
        var JumlahTHR = jumlahthr.toInt()
        var hasil = gajipokok * MasaKerja * JumlahTHR
        return hasil
    }
}
```

when the program is run, only the display "Perhitungan THR" appears. The second function does not appear when the program is run.

Comment: What did you expect? The second function does not `print` anything.

Comment: You are never printing anything in the second method, put `thr.hitungthr(5000000, "1", 1.5)` in print, it would `print` the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the value returned by the function hitungthr

```
fun main() {
    val thr = THR()
    thr.kotlin()
    print(thr.hitungthr(5000000, "1", 1.5))
}
```

Try to add print() in your main() function and try it.